# Como extrar texto desde un PDF ESCANEADO en Python

Tags: python, django

Tengo el siguiente codigo que extrae o separa el pdf en imagenes, la idea es extraer una pagina en especifico y de esa imagen obtener el texto.

```
#extrae imagenes desde pdf
import sys

#definimos el pdf ->path
pdf = file(path, "rb").read()

startmark = "\xff\xd8"
startfix = 0
endmark = "\xff\xd9"
endfix = 2
i = 0

njpg = 0
while True:
    istream = pdf.find("stream", i)
    if istream < 0:
        break
    istart = pdf.find(startmark, istream, istream+20)
    if istart < 0:
        i = istream+20
        continue
    iend = pdf.find("endstream", istart)
    if iend < 0:
        raise Exception("no se encontro el fin de stream!")
    iend = pdf.find(endmark, iend-20)
    if iend < 0:
        raise Exception("no se encontro el fin de  JPG!")

    istart += startfix
    iend += endfix


    jpg = pdf[istart:iend]
    jpgfile = file("jpg%d.jpg" % njpg, "wb")
    jpgfile.write(jpg)
    jpgfile.close()

    njpg += 1
    i = iend    
print ("finalizado")
```

las imagenes que obtengo mediante esa funcion son algo asi:
[image: Modelo de imagen obtenida]

gracias cualquier sugerencia o comentario !!

Comment: Es decir, lo que buscas es hacer OCR (optical character recognition) sobre una imagen? Sería bueno que compartieras alguna de estas imágenes.

Comment: buena sugerencia ya lo hago gracias !!

Comment: REvisa esto, te será de utilidad: http://aniversarioperu.utero.pe/2013/12/27/periodismo-de-datos-capitulo-03/

Comment: gracias @fredyfx muy interesante el articulo lo voy a probar !!

Comment: de nada hermano, me alegro que te haya sido interesante, ¡buena suerte! Cuando lo hagas funcionar, redacta tu respuesta, creces tú y la comunidad crece contigo, crece la comunidad y tú creces con ella :D

Comment: En ocasiones, según de qué fuente obtengas el PDF, además de la imagen escaneada el pdf contiene el "texto plano" resultado de un OCR. Puedes notarlo porque la búsqueda de texto dentro del PDF funciona, así como el seleccionar, copiar y pegar. Si ese fuera el caso, lo más sencillo sería extraer el texto en lugar de la imagen. Prueba con `pdftotext` a ver si sale algo

Comment: Personalmente he usado hace poco [pyocr](https://pypi.org/project/pyocr/) + [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) como motor para algo muy similar con muy buenos resultados, aunque en mi caso eran imágenes escaneadas con buena calidad y estandarizadas. He probado con tu imagen y el resultado es bastante bueno, no he comprobado palabra a palabra pero los únicos fallos que detecto son en la parte derecha de la cabecera, dónde viene la dirección y tal, zona con fuente pequeña y algo borrosa.

Comment: @abulafia gracias por el comentario entiendo lo del texto plano pero la verdad es un texto/documento que al ser escaneado automaticamente se convierte en pdf sin posibilidad de dar texto plano y de hecho si he tratado con ello de pdftotext no genera error tan solo retorna vacio el resultado+

Comment: @FJSevilla gracias por tu comentario lo voy a probar !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego la respuesta si a alguien le sirviera:
Como sabemos el PDF escaneado es una conjunto de imagenes, es decir para poder extrar el texto tendriamos que pasar a imagenes y estas a texto.

**Pasando pdf a imagenes:**

```
#convertir pdf a imagen
    from wand.image import Image
    #estableciendo resolucion a imagen
    with Image(filename=path_absoluta, resolution=400) as img:
        #estableciendo ancho y alto
        img.resize(1850,1850)
        img.save(filename="media/normas/temp.jpg")
```

Como se nota uso wand , donde **path_absoluta** vendria a ser la ruta del pdf deseado y el numero de pagina a convertir a imagen.

**Extrayendo el texto de la imagen:**

```
import pytesseract
    from PIL import ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
    from PIL import Image as Img
    im = Img.open("media/normas/temp.jpg")
    im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())

    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
    #aplicando filtro para mejorar la convercion de imagen->txt
    im = enhancer.enhance(15)
    im = im.convert('1')
    im.save('sample.jpeg')

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Img.open('sample.jpeg'), lang='spa')
```

En este caso he usado la imagen anterior(temp.jpg), he usado **Pillow**  y sus filtros para crear una nueva mejora a la imagen anterior y luego de esto extraer el texto de dicha imagen.. y listo tendriamos todo en text.

**Links:**

[Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/)

[Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/)